# how to extend/specify Yii2's relations?

Tags: yii2, relation

I'm wondering about performance and thinking about how to narrow down my SQL queries. Therefore I have the following question:

Let's say we have following relations:

```
public function getOrders() {
    return $this->hasMany(Orders::className(), ['fk_product_id' => 'id']);
}

public function getOrdersByDate() {
    return $this->hasMany(Orders::className(), ['fk_product_id' => 'id'])->orderBy('date');
}
```

So the question is, is there a way to connect these two relations without having to make extra SQL query when I call for `$model->ordersByDate`? I know I could go through the first relation with foreach() and sort it to get the result of 2nd relation, but that doesn't seem very wise.

Comment: Why do you need to do two identical queries with different ordering? I'm not sure i get your problem here.. Could you elaborate? -> whats your desired result?

Comment: This is just an example. But I generally need to use same data in different places with different parameters. For example, somewhere else I might need to narrow `getOrders()` with `->where(['type' => 'x'])`. So when I'm using `getOrders()` anyway, I wouldn't need to make another query if I could specify the already made query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `->with()` to get all the information at once

```
Model::find()->with('orders')->with('ordersByDate')->all()
```

and then reference them with `$model->orders`

Or you can get the orders once with `getOrders` and sort/find in the array later.

Unless you could be more specific in what kind of queries you're running, and you want a solution you can adapt to several different issues, you just have to read up :)

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper.html

check the BaseArrayHelper::index()

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_sort.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

> $fruits = array("d"=>"lemon", "a"=>"orange", "b"=>"banana", "c"=>"apple");
>
> ksort($fruits);
>
> foreach ($fruits as $key => $val) {
>
> echo "$key = $val\n";
>
> }